# CSS Resizing based on key variables

Tags: css, responsive-design

I've built a dynamically sized grid layout that can adapt to reasonably in any sized resolution (phone, tablet, desktop) and handle resizing, all while being near pixel-perfect (sorry, I'm OCD -- and I say "near" because my math is broken right now and you can't fit two evenly sized elements inside of an odd sized container without padding being 1px off on one side).

Anyway, below is a link to what I've hacked together with JavaScript.  It's an example of what I'm trying to pull off.  Resize the width of the bottom pane a bit to see what I'm going for.

http://jsfiddle.net/langdonx/uFW2C/2/

It has some ugly manual JavaScript that's since been ported to Angular, but still the ugly JavaScript that calculates all the styles remains.

**So my question**... can I pull this off with strictly CSS?  Or a lot more CSS and a lot less JavaScript?  And by this I mean dynamically sized cells based on the width of the screen?

Here are the *business* rules:

- Max cell width: 320px
- Minimum # cells per row: 2

  - *this might be impossible with CSS, so I'd be fine with settling on Min Cell Width: 178 for Chrome on my Galaxy Nexus(whose portait mode is 360px wide)*
- Cell border: 5px with a 2px outline
- Visible margin between cells: 3px (margin is actually 5px, but `outline` bleeds out)

In this example, I'm redrawing the cells on resize every time, but in my Angular version, I believe that just the styles get updated.  That said, I could probably get away with redrawing a `table` on resize, but I'd only have to calculate the cell width based on the document width, and well... I wouldn't be thrilled to use a `table`. =[

-end mad rant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Media queries**

[CSS media queries](http://www.w3.org/TR/css3-mediaqueries/) might get you pretty close to a CSS-only solution.

The key concept here is using different layout grids based on the width of the browser, to vary the number of columns.

Media queries are the natural CSS way to change the layout based on the browser width. And they require no JavaScript. If you use a set of media queries -- each one targetting a different range of browser widths -- to control which layout grid is used, then all each grid has to do is be responsive -- percentage widths for each column, and let the content stretch to fill the column width.

**Responsive Design**

The question then becomes: Is it possible to automatically stretch each piece of content to fill the column using CSS alone? That depends on the type of content, how it's expected to behave when it stretches, and if there's any room for compromise with the graphic design.

Typically, the graphic design for a responsive website has to be tailored to suit the limitations of Responsive Design (with the graphic designers having a rough idea of what's feasible and what isn't). But... whatever can't be done automatically, can be done using JavaScript.

Relevant search terms for attempting to stretch the content: *Responsive Design*, *Adaptive Content*, *[Fluid Grid](http://www.alistapart.com/articles/responsive-web-design/)*

Note: "Columns" in this case may simply mean the percentage width used for the floated containers for each piece of content. It doesn't have to mean "physical" columns, in the traditional sense.